# How to display this json response?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to display the products array data from the following JSON response in the most simple way possible:

name, id, code

What I'm having trouble with is getting to the products array. I'm not proficient in javascript/jquery so any help is much appreciated.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "zip product 1",
        "id": "44",
        "code": "ZIP1"
      },
      {
        "name": "zoo product 1",
        "id": "45",
        "code": "ZOO1"
      },
      {
        "name": "zip product 2",
        "id": "46",
        "code": "Zip2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a JSON prettifier to format your data. You will may be understand the structure better. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resultsObject = <that-data>;
var productsArray = resultsObject.data.products;
```

should give you access to products array

```js
var resultsObject = {
  "success": 1,
  "data": {
    "products": [{
      "name": "zip product 1",
      "id": "44",
      "code": "ZIP1"
    }, {
      "name": "zoo product 1",
      "id": "45",
      "code": "ZOO1"
    }, {
      "name": "zip product 2",
      "id": "46",
      "code": "Zip2"
    }]
  }
};
var productsArray = resultsObject.data.products;
console.log(productsArray);
```

Comment: That helped me make progress. I was able to get the json response into the variable by settings resultsObject to JSON.parse(data); - I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = json.data.products;

for(var i=0; i< products.length; products++)
{
   console.log(products[i].id);
   console.log(products[i].name);
   console.log(products[i].code);
}
```